# How can I escape backticks in gnu make makefile

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I have this make file:

```
createuser:
        $(MYSQL) -e " grant SELECT, USAGE  on `app\_%`.* to 'user.name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$(USER_PASS)'" && \
        $(MYSQL) -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

This command works fine if I execute it directly in a MySQL query window, but I want to execute it from terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` with `GRANT` or `CREATE USER`
   statements
2. For future compatibility - `CREATE USER [IF NOT EXISTS]`
   before doing the `GRANT`
3. Within a Makefile you can escape using `\`
   before both backticks.